# check for valid arguments

Tags: python

So let's define a few functions:

```
def x(a, b, c): pass
def y(a, b=1, c=2): pass
def z(a=1, b=2, c=3): pass
```

Now, what's the best way to, given a pointer to `x`, `y`, or `z` (`p`), a tuple of args (`a`) and a dictionary of kwargs (`k`), check to see if

```
p(*a, **kw)
```

would produce any exception regarding having not enough arguments or incorrect arguments, etc—*without* actually calling `p(*a, **kw)` and then catching the exceptions raised.

### Example

```
def valid(ptr, args, kwargs): ... #implementation here

valid(x, ("hello", "goodbye", "what?"), {}) # => True
valid(x, ("hello", "goodbye"), {}) # => False
valid(y, ("hello", "goodbye", "what?"), {}) # => True
valid(y, (), {"a": "hello", "b": "goodbye", "c": "what"}) #=> True
valid(y, ("hello", "goodbye"), {"c": "what?"}) #=> True
```

Comment: And why do you need to do that? Calling the function and catching any exception then is the way Python is designed to be used (see [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp)).

Comment: Because the function that I'm trying to call may throw a `TypeError` not related to the arguments I receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way that I can think of to do this is to create a new function with the exact same signature and defaults and try to call that and catch the exception. The body of the new function's code should just be `pass` so that there are no side effects. There's nothing really profound here, the code is just tedious. It's worth noting that this does tie you to CPython internals. It works on 2.6. You'd have to port it to other versions but that shouldn't be too hard.

```
import types


ARGS_FLAG = 4   #If memory serves, this can be found in code.h in the Python source.
KWARGS_FLAG = 8

def valid(f, args, kwargs):

    def dummy():
        pass

    dummy_code = dummy.func_code
    real_code = f.func_code

    args_flag = real_code.co_flags & ARGS_FLAG
    kwargs_flag = real_code.co_flags & KWARGS_FLAG

    # help(types.CodeType) for details
    test_code = types.CodeType(real_code.co_argcount,
                               real_code.co_nlocals,
                               dummy_code.co_stacksize,
                               args_flag | kwargs_flag,
                               dummy_code.co_code,
                               dummy_code.co_consts,
                               dummy_code.co_names,
                               real_code.co_varnames,
                               "<test>", "", 0, "", ())

    # help(types.FunctionType) for details
    test_func = types.FunctionType(test_code, {}, "test", f.func_defaults)

    try:
        test_func(*args, **kwargs)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def x(a, b, c): pass
def y(a, b=1, c=2): pass
def z(a=1, b=2, c=3): pass

print valid(x, ("hello", "goodbye", "what?"), {}) # => True
print valid(x, ("hello", "goodbye"), {}) # => False
print valid(y, ("hello", "goodbye", "what?"), {}) # => True
print valid(y, (), {"a": "hello", "b": "goodbye", "c": "what"}) #=> True
print valid(y, ("hello", "goodbye"), {"c": "what?"}) #=> True
```

Running this code yields:

```
$ python argspec.py
True
False
True
True
True
```

Comment: After a simple `2to3` this code is producing 'need an int' errors in Python 3. What's going on?

Comment: @aharon, it's hard for me to say. I'll go ahead and port it real fast.

Comment: @aharon, [here](https://gist.github.com/802506) it is for python 3. The main problem was that a new keyword only argument got added to the code constructor in python 3 and that the lnotab argument shifted to needing bytes instead of a string.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `inspect` module's `getargspec` function to determine the functions of the arguments and their defaults, if any, as well as if the function accepts varargs or keywordargs. This should be enough information to determine if a given tuple will satisfy the argument requirements.

Here's a start (have to run, but I figured posting a start was better than nothing).

```
def valid(f, *args, **kwargs):
    specs = getargspec(f)
    required = specs.args[:-len(specs.defaults)] if (specs.defaults != None) else specs.args 
    #Now just check that your required arguments list is fulfilled by args and kwargs
    #And check that no args are left over, unless the argspec has varargs or kwargs defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this method signature type check decorator:

Python 3: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572161/
Python 2: same site/.../recipes/426123/

It is easier to use in Python 3 because it uses annotations for type specifications, very intuitive:

```
@typecheck
def foo(a1: int, a2: str, a3: dict, *, kw1: bool) -> list:
    ...

@typecheck
def bar(el: list_of(str),
        stream: with_attr("write", "flush"),
        num: by_regex("^[0-9]+$"),
        f: optional(callable) = None):
    ...

@typecheck
def biz(p: lambda x: isinstance(x, int) and x % 3 == 0):
    ...
```

etc.

The Python 2 version is not so pretty, but still usable:

```
@takes(int, str, dict, kw1 = bool)
@returns(list)
def foo(a1, a2, a3, **kwargs):
    ...
```